# how do i find application name using GUID from error in event viewer on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, eventviewer, com+, guid

A Windows Serve 2003 machine logged an error in Event Viewer with the COM+ Event System, saying it could not marshal the subscriber for a particular subscription and then gave the SID/GUID, which is:

```
{DF540FFA-D787-4FDF-82E4-4BD5C1302F23}-{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}-{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.  The HRESULT was 800706BB.
```

I don't quite understand the error.

I'm trying to look up the GUID to find the application.

I tried opening up the registry and searching for it but it didn't find anything.  A google research revealed I need to load the cluster database in the registry and look up the GUID.  The problem is I cannot find the CLUSDB file.  It is not in %SystemRoot%\Cluster.

What do I need to do to identify the application in question?

Answer (score 4):

Open up regedit and search for the key under:

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{DF540FFA-D787-4FDF-82E4-4BD5C1302F23}

And the default key should provide you a user friendly name.

Comment: Although this may not always work.  I have an error today with the first CLSID being "runtime broker" followed by another CLSID "runtime broker".  This is followed by an S- identifier which took a lot of sleuthing to find out was OneDrive Icon Resource not working because I also have another application that overlays the explorer icons.  (I really resent Microsoft developers sometimes)

Answer (score 3):

Run dcomcnfg or comexp.msc. (They're the same thing.)

Expand Component Services, Computers, My Computer, COM+ Applications

Right click on one of the installed components and click Properties.

The UUID or GUID or whatever you want to call it of your application is there.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Unfortunately, I didn't see the GUID/UUID listed as one of the installed components.  Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 3):

When opening Component Services, as [Ryan Ries](https://serverfault.com/a/343196) suggests, You can quickly see the Application IDs of every COM application like this:

1. In the left-hand menu, drill down into *Component Services* -> *My Computer* -> *COM+ Applications*.
2. Right click on *COM+ Applications*, and go to *View* and select *Detail*.

[image: Image of Component Services application]

Do note that the error message you're seeing might correspond to an App ID as Ryan anticipates, or to a CLSID, as [sverach](https://serverfault.com/a/893351/) suggests. I'm not really sure. I got a different error message that contained both.

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
>
> {...}
>
> and APPID
>
> {...}
>
> to the user ... from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.